# Contextual understanding of text using NLP

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, speech-to-text

I am building a voice assistant using Google Speech to Text API. The text that is transcribed through the API is later used for building reports the client can use. 
The challenge I am facing with this is that about 2/10 times, the Speech to Text conversion is not accurate. eg. "Hello" might be transcribed as "ello" and complexer word combinations like "Thymic Horns" (medical word) are transcribed as "Thymic vows". While these issues are most definitely caused by incorrect pronounciation, there is still a need to fix these spelling errors using contextual understanding of sentences. 
My question is, what are the best algorithms in NLP that I can use to address these issues? And what is the kind of data I have to use to train the model to attain maximum possible accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use word2vec contextual models. They can define the missing word by its context.
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html